# Creating a silent unattended installer using prepackaged NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have a prepackaged NSIS installer exe which I want to make fully silent or an unattended installer. I used switches like : /S and /NCRC /S but still when I run it, still windows show up asking to click NEXT ACCEPT ....
Is there any other solution for this?
Please help I'm new and just want to have an unattended installer from that prepackaged software.

Comment: Did you write this installer or did you get it from a 3rd-party?

Comment: @Anders yes I got it from a 3rd party. That's why I don't have the code for the installer. What do you recommend for looking into the installer? Any software?

Comment: Old beta versions of 7-zip can sort of decompile the installers but the only real solution is to ask the people that wrote the installer...

Answer (score 0):

Passing the /S switch (CASE sensitive!) is not enough: you need to *write* the installer to be really silent.

Do you have sources (scripts) for your installer? What you need is to

1. Detect silent mode (**IfSilent**)
2. Update MessageBox with /SD parameter to let installer know what button to 'click' in silent mode
3. Solve your Sections

Check this example and made appropriate changes: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Examples/silent.nsi

Comment: I don't have the source but I only got the end file (the .exe version). In order to see the code and edit it to be silent, what software do you recommend to use? I tried PE Explorer but can't save the file, and tried 7zip as well, but still didn't work.

Comment: I don't have the source of my exe file. I only got the .exe file and tried to check the source using PE Explorer and edit the manifest file. Tried 7zip as well but it extracted to another exe file and couldn't see any code. 
I'm so new to this, which software do you recommend for checking the code of the exe file for editing.
I'm sure that there's a way to check the code and create the silent version to click those next next buttons.
Sorry, DOUBLE POST!

Comment: This is not possible without sources (scripts). No disassemble software (IdaPro, OllyDbg, Pe Explorer) can do this. Ask your software supplier to make appropriate changhes.